# How to prove that the canonical inclusion of $V_1^\ast\otimes \cdots \otimes V_n^\ast$ into $(V_1\otimes\cdots\otimes V_n)^\ast$ is an inclusion

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

I read these threads: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31206/why-is-the-inclusion-of-the-tensor-product-of-the-duals-into-the-dual-of-the-ten), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663665/is-v-1-otimes-cdots-otimes-v-k-ast-simeq-v-1-ast-otimes-cdots-otimes-v-k?noredirect=1&lq=1), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544668/relation-between-textbilv-w-and-textbilv-w), but my question is somewhat simpler, maybe trivial — sorry in advance, if this is the case.
**How do we prove, in the general case, that the canonical inclusion is indeed an inclusion?**
By using a couple of times the universal property of the tensor product (on different environments) we build a linear map, let's say $F: V_1^\ast\otimes\dots\otimes V_n^\ast \to(V_1\otimes\dots\otimes V_n)^\ast$, such that:

$$F(\phi_1\otimes\dots\otimes\phi_n)\left(\boldsymbol{v}_1\otimes \dots\otimes\boldsymbol{v}_n\right)=\phi_1(\boldsymbol{v}_1)\dots\phi_n(\boldsymbol{v}_n);$$

for any $(\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n)\in V_1^\ast\times\dots\times V_n^\ast$ and $(\boldsymbol{v}_1, \dots,\boldsymbol{v}_n)\in V_1\times\dots\times V_n$; so… **how do we get that $F$ is injective?**
I'm ok with the finite-dimensional case, but I can't see how to adapt its proof to the general case: the one I'm aware of rests upon the fact that each linear functional (covector) can be decomposed on the dual basis.
Of course I tried to show that the kernel of $F$ is trivial; now, I can see why — hope what I'm about to write is not wrong — if $F$ vanishes on a simple tensor $\phi_1\otimes\dots\otimes\phi_n$, then this latter vanishes too; but then $V_1^\ast\otimes\dots\otimes V_n^\ast$ is made up of all the finite sums of such tensors, so how do I manage such a case?

I'm not familiar with categories, so, in order to be sure that I can follow your answer, please keep things as simple as possible; eg, should pairings, evaluation contractions, and/or canonical isomorphisms be needed, please don't give for granted that I'm already able to follow you on everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will show it in the case of two factors
$$V^{\star} \otimes W ^{\star} \to (V \otimes W)^{\star}$$

Consider an element on LHS $\sum \alpha_{ij} k_i\otimes l_j$
where $k_i \in V_1^{\star}$, $l_j \in V_2^{\star}$ linearly independent. We know that for every $v \otimes w \in V_1 \otimes V_2$ we have
$$\sum \alpha_{ij}l_i(v) k_j (w)=0$$

Now fix $w \in W$. Then we have for every $v\in V$
$$\sum_i( \sum \alpha_{ij} k_j(w)) l_i(v) = 0$$
Since the $l_i$ are linearly independent we get
$$\sum_j \alpha_{ij}k_j(w)=0$$
for all $i$.  Now since the $k_j$ are also independent we get $\alpha_{ij} =0$ for all $i$, $j$.

Note that we did not use anywhere the fact that the $l_i$, $k_j$ are linear. This is connected to the fact that the map
$$\mathcal{F}(X, \mathbb{K}) \otimes \mathcal{F}(Y, \mathbb{K})\to \mathcal{F}(X\times Y, \mathbb{K})$$
is injective, where $\mathcal{F}(X, \mathbb{K})$ is a space of functions.

Answer (score 4):

I will prove this in the case $n=2$; the argument for general $n$ is almost identical but the notation is messier.

So, suppose $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over a field $k$, and we wish to show your map $F:V^*\otimes W^*\to (V\otimes W)^*$ is injective.  The idea is that every element of $V^*\otimes W^*$ actually comes from some finite-dimensional quotients of $V$ and $W$, so that you can reduce to the case where $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional.

Specifically, suppose $x=\sum_{i=1}^m f_i\otimes g_i\in \ker(F)$.  Let $f:V\to k^m$ and $g:W\to k^m$ be the linear maps whose coordinates are the $f_i$ and $g_i$.  Let $V_0=\ker f$ and $W_0=\ker g$.  Note that the quotient map $V\to V/V_0$ induces a linear injection $(V/V_0)^*\to V^*$ (the inclusion of the functionals on $V$ that happen to vanish on $V_0$), and similarly there is a linear injection $(W/W_0)^*\to W^*$.  Tensoring these together we get a linear injection $\alpha:(V/V_0)^*\otimes (W/W_0)^*\to V^*\otimes W^*$.  By construction, our element $x=\sum f_i\otimes g_i$ is in the image of $\alpha$, since each $f_i$ vanishes on $V_0$ and each $g_i$ vanishes on $W_0$.  Also, $V/V_0$ and $W/W_0$ are finite-dimensional, since they are isomorphic to the images of $f$ and $g$.

We can also tensor the quotient maps together to get a linear surjection $V\otimes W\to V/V_0\otimes W/W_0$ which dualizes to a linear injection $\beta:(V/V_0\otimes W/W_0)^*\to (V\otimes W)^*$.  These maps all fit into a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(V/V_0)^*\otimes (W/W_0)^* @>{F'}>> (V/V_0\otimes W/W_0)^*\\
@V{\alpha}VV @V{\beta}VV \\
V^*\otimes W^* @>{F}>> (V\otimes W)^*
\end{CD}$$ where the top map $F'$ is just your $F$ for the pair of vector spaces $V/V_0$ and $W/W_0$ instead of $V$ and $W$.  Since $V/V_0$ and $W/W_0$ are finite-dimensional, we know that $F'$ is an isomorphism.  Now, our element $x\in \ker(F)$ is in the image of $\alpha$; say $x=\alpha(y)$.  We then have $$0=F(x)=F(\alpha(y))=\beta(F'(y)).$$  But $\beta$ and $F'$ are injective, so this implies $y=0$, so $x=\alpha(y)=0$.  Thus we have shown an arbitrary element of $\ker F$ is $0$, so $F$ is injective.

Comment: Thaanks a lot, mate. I will have to accept the other answer because it is more "elementary", so it is closer according to how the question had been formulated. Nonetheless, you solved my problem; also, this technique of using quotient spaces in order to deal with finite dimensional spaces is very interesting.

Comment: May I ask, in $x=\sum_{i=1}^m f_i\otimes g_i\in \ker(F)$, why using the same index for both $f$ and $g$? Don't $V^*$ and $W^*$ have different dimensions?

Comment: @user760: What do the dimensions have to do with it?  That's just the form of an arbitrary element of the tensor product: a sum of some elements of the form $f\otimes g$.

Comment: Ah ok, got it. Thanks