# Is the canonical map $(\prod_{i \in I} V_i)\otimes (\prod_{j \in J} W_j)\to \prod_{(i,j)\in I\times J} V_i\otimes W_j$ injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $k$ be a field and $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $\{W_j\}_{j \in J}$ be a collection of $k$-vector spaces. We have a canonical map
$$\left(\prod_{i \in I} V_i\right)\otimes \left(\prod_{j \in J} W_j\right)\to \prod_{(i,j)\in I\times J} V_i\otimes W_j: (v_i)_{i \in I}\otimes (w_j)_{j \in J}\mapsto (v_i\otimes w_j)_{(i,j)\in I\times J}.$$
Is this map injective in general? I can prove this for the direct sum, because there I can simply use a basis, however the direct product doesn't have a nice basis so I don't know how to proceed here. I tried tricks with linear independency, linear functionals etc.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @WilliamM. How is that a counterexample?

Comment: I confused the left-hand tensor product with a Cartesian product. This made me wonder, what definition of tensor product are you using? I often work with $V \otimes W$ as the set of all bilinear forms on $V \times W$ of the form $(a,b) \mapsto x(a) y(b)$ with $x$ and $y$ linear forms on $V$ and $W,$ respectively. When applied to a Cartesian product, I reach a bilinear form $((a_i), (b_j)) \mapsto x((a_i)) y((b_j)),$ with $x$ and $y$ linear on $\prod V_i$ and $\prod W_j,$ but I fail to identify them with $(v_i)$ and $(w_j).$ So, our definitions of tensor product probably differ.

Comment: See also this closely related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4232175/how-to-prove-that-the-canonical-inclusion-of-v-1-ast-otimes-cdots-otimes-v-n (which is essentially just the special case of your question where each $V_i$ and $W_j$ is 1-dimensional).

Comment: @WilliamM It doesn't matter what definition of the tensor product one uses, as long as it satisfies the universal property of the tensor product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this map is always injective.  It suffices to show the canonical map $$\left(\prod_{i \in I} V_i\right)\otimes W\to \prod_{i\in I}(V_i\otimes W)$$ is always injective, since you can use this twice (first with $W=\prod_{j\in j}W_j$ and then on each $V_i\otimes W$ swapping the roles of the two sides of the tensor) to deduce injectivity of your map.  But now note that any element of $\left(\prod_{i \in I} V_i\right)\otimes W$ actually comes from $\left(\prod_{i \in I} V_i\right)\otimes W_0$ for some finite-dimensional subspace $W_0\subseteq W$, and there is a commutative square

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\left(\prod_{i \in I} V_i\right)\otimes W_0 @>{}>> \prod_{i\in I}(V_i\otimes W_0)\\
@V{}VV @V{}VV \\
\left(\prod_{i \in I} V_i\right)\otimes W @>{}>> \prod_{i\in I}(V_i\otimes W)
\end{CD}$$
in which the vertical maps are injective, so it suffices to show the top map is injective.  In other words, we may assume $W$ is finite-dimensional.  But in that case it is easy to see that the map is in fact an isomorphism, since each side preserves finite direct sums in the $W$ variable and the map is an isomorphism when $W=k$.

Comment: Lovely argument! Thanks for the answer!