Canonical Isomorphisms for Tensor Products
I'm trying to find a canonical isomorphism between $ (V \otimes W)^{dual} $ and $V^{dual}\otimes W^{dual}$. However, I'm somewhat confused of what applying the dual to a tensor product space would mean.
Could someone give me hints of what that means? What is the intuition behind this?
Thanks

What is the adjoint of a vector space? Do you mean the dual?

Sorry, I meant the dual

You may find this helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31206/why-is-the-inclusion-of-the-tensor-product-of-the-duals-into-the-dual-of-the-ten

I think of $V \otimes W$ as the vector space of finite sums of the form $\sum_i v_i \otimes w_i$ (with the usual rule that the symbol $\otimes$ is bilinear in each argument). This is just any other old vector space, so its dual is functions on this space.

"Could someone give me hints of what that means?" A good place to start is with the dual. What does taking the dual of a vector space mean to you?
